# Modify outlet inside UITableView custom cell

Tags: uitableview, iboutlet

I have a custom UITableViewCell that has 2 UITextFields and a `UIButton`. The text fields are set in the `cell:ForRow:AtIndexPath:` method. What I need is to change the opacity of this `UIButton` dynamically, without having to reload the entire tableview. I was thinking of something like `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, but how to access the outlet in this cell?

Thanks

Comment: u have to reload the table if you want any changes to be reflected

Comment: Reload the data or the input views?

Comment: make any changes you need and reload the data [tableView reloadData];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath: just maintain a pointer to it in code. If that button is on every cell then you can just create an array of buttons so that you can easily access the button for the cell you want.

```
UIButton *cellButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[allCellButtons addObject:cellButton];
```

Comment: Actually this button is declared in the .h and linked to a UIButton in the Interface Builder.

Comment: The button that is going on the cells is declared in .h file? Is there a reason it has to be there and you can't create it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: call?

Comment: Only that it's simpler to have an outlet and set it's properties in the IB than create the button dynamically.

Comment: Then reload the data in the table like Sharanya said

Comment: I'm trying that and the buttons won't show up immediaely. They will only appear when I scroll the TableView. What might it be?